# What is the proper way to use pytorch and matplotlib with MKL on Windows?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pytorch, intel-mkl

Is there any clear instruction on how to actually make this work?

The error message I get is:

> Error #15: Initializing libiomp5md.dll, but found libiomp5md.dll already initialized.

It seems, there are only workarounds, such as to opt out from MKL altogether (not to mention, say, `nomkl` is not available on Windows) or

```
import os

os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'
```

which is nasty.

Answer (score 2):

If you have conda and pip installed on your machine. Please try installing by creating a new conda environment. You could try the below steps  (which I have validated from my end) to install matplotlib and pytorch (with mkl).

```
conda create -n myenv
conda activate myenv
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cpuonly -c pytorch
C:\Users\{USERNAME}\.conda\envs\myenv\python.exe -m pip install matplotlib==2.2.5
```

Once installed I verified pytorch uses mkl with the below command

```
>>> import torch
>>> torch.__config__.show()
'PyTorch built with:\n  - C++ Version: 199711\n  - MSVC 192829337\n  - Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 2020.0.2 Product Build 20200624 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications\n  - Intel(R) MKL-DNN v2.2.3 (Git Hash 7336ca9f055cf1bfa13efb658fe15dc9b41f0740)\n  - OpenMP 2019\n  - LAPACK is enabled (usually provided by MKL)\n  - CPU capability usage: AVX2\n  - Build settings: BLAS_INFO=mkl, BUILD_TYPE=Release, CXX_COMPILER=C:/cb/pytorch_1000000000000/work/tmp_bin/sccache-cl.exe, CXX_FLAGS=/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /GR /EHsc /w /bigobj -DUSE_PTHREADPOOL -openmp:experimental -IC:/cb/pytorch_1000000000000/work/mkl/include -DNDEBUG -DUSE_KINETO -DLIBKINETO_NOCUPTI -DUSE_FBGEMM -DUSE_XNNPACK -DSYMBOLICATE_MOBILE_DEBUG_HANDLE -DEDGE_PROFILER_USE_KINETO, LAPACK_INFO=mkl, PERF_WITH_AVX=1, PERF_WITH_AVX2=1, PERF_WITH_AVX512=1, TORCH_VERSION=1.10.0, USE_CUDA=0, USE_CUDNN=OFF, USE_EXCEPTION_PTR=1, USE_GFLAGS=OFF, USE_GLOG=OFF, USE_MKL=ON, USE_MKLDNN=ON, USE_MPI=OFF, USE_NCCL=OFF, USE_NNPACK=OFF, USE_OPENMP=ON, \n'
```